# Double click on formatted text, how to affect selection behavior?

Tags: xcode, macos, syntax

Using XCode, I would like to modify what is selected when double-clicking some formatted text.

Say I have a plain text file, containing series of lines such as

```
seed:seedTest1
name:name1;method:1;
name:name2;method:1;type:4

seed:seedTest2
...
```

As I double click on `name1` for instance, the whole `name:name1` gets selected. I would like to have only `name1` selected. Is it possible to define how double clicks behave, what boundaries should be taken in account?

Thanks,

Comment: Is this a question about how to change the text editing behaviors in the Xcode IDE, or in a Mac app you're developing using said IDE? Please phrase/tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Ok, so I want to change the behavior of the IDE. In the example above, a seed.txt file is opened.

Answer (score 0):

That was driving me crazy too, try this,

System Preferences->Language & Text->Text-> Change "Word Break" to "English (United States, Computer)"